# Fedora Live Usb won't boot

Tags: fedora, bootable-media, liveusb, installation-media

I have written the fedora 22 32-bit iso to a 32gb usb thumb drive with the dd command in ubuntu 15.04. The terminal stated the write was successful.  I have verified my iso isnt corrupt with the SHA256SUM.

When I try to boot, I get the following message:

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I would really like to install fedora 22 to my desktop,  but it won't boot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your USB was almost certainly not written correctly, e.g. your USB thumb drive might need replacing.

In theory, you need to use a method of writing to the USB which re-checks the written data.  This can be quite difficult, sorry.

Exhaustive explanation of this specific error: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453272/kernel-panic-while-installing-fedora-28/453307#453307

Ironically, the simplest suggestion I have is if you also have a Windows computer available.  Download *Fedora Media Writer* on Windows.  Optionally, *Fedora Media Writer* can also download and verify the iso file for you.  Whatever way you download the iso to Windows, you can then use *Fedora Media Writer* to write it to the USB, and it will automatically re-check the data on the USB after it has been written.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved this way:
Zero the USB using `dd`.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX
```

***Warning***: Make sure you replace sdX with the correct block device by running `lsblk` without the USB plugged in, and then with it plugged in, otherwise you may irrecoverably overwrite your boot disk.

Now burn the iso file on it again.

Comment: Readers, PLEASE BE AWARE that on some systems, this specific command will "format" (COMPLETELY OVERWRITE) an internal hard drive instead. Take great care when specifying the `of=` parameter.  In theory there should be no reason to overwrite with zeros first - it should be just as effective to write the Fedora-Workstation-Live 28 to the USB a second time, without zeroing the drive first.